# CSS overlapping divs top bar

Tags: html, css

I want to create the following structure with HTML / css:

[image: CSS overlapping]

I wonder which div to make first. The green one and place the black with an position or the black and place the green one on top of it.

Could someone advise how to do?

The red box is general content.

Comment: Please add the code to your question. It will be easy for the people to help you with your problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8wnry2f/) for the solution

```
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="black"></div>

<style>

.red {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
border: 5px solid red;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.green {
height: 30px;
width: 100%;
border: 5px solid green;
margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.black {
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
border: 5px solid black;
z-index:-1;
position: absolute;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use negative margin-bottom for green div. Something like this:

```
<STYLE>
div.black {
  z-index: 10;
}
div.green {
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  z-index: 100;
}
</STYLE>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make them in the order red, green ,black, then simply give the green div a negative bottom margin.